# Show divs with a given class first

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm wondering if there is a pure css solution for displaying divs with a given class first, and divs without that class last, independently of in what order they appear in the html code.

For example, for this html:

```
<div>6</div>
<div class="first">1</div>
<div class="first">3</div>
<div>2</div>
<div class="first">5</div>
<div>4</div>
```

divs should be displayed one under the another in this order:

1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6

#### NOTE:

I know how to solve the problem in javascript, I want to know if there exists a pure css solution.

Comment: Dear gentleman who downvoted my question, can you please explain why you did it?

Comment: Why this question has been downvoted ?

Comment: Working on something that makes use of *{float:right;} and .first{float:left} could be hard but could work.

Comment: `div {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    float: right;
}

.first {
    float: left;
}`
If you want to show in on left side, just wrap it with div and give that new div CSS `float: right;` style

Comment: @AndrewSpartan - unfortunately it's not that simple: http://jsbin.com/eyativ/1/edit

Comment: With float, divs will be inline. I don't think that is a solution.

Comment: @Brewal the width could then be set to 100%.

Comment: @TamasPap Your css is invalid. Remove one `{` and it (kind of) work. However with float:right the order will be reversed.

Comment: Then try this http://jsbin.com/eworol/1/

@Brewal Maybe not. Let the OP explayne to us :)

Comment: @Christoph You are right, corrected it.

Comment: @ChenAsraf Try it. It won't be in the correct order : http://jsfiddle.net/Ck6dq/. Same with inline-block.

Comment: @AndrewSpartan This is close to what I want, but I need to display them one above the other.

Comment: Trying to look at this in different way. 
If this content do not generating by PHP (or anything else) you can just sort content manually. 
If content generating by code you can control output- if your element have class first- just output it, if it haven't you write it to variable- and then just output this entire variable.

Answer (score 3):

You may use float

CSS

```css
#container > div { display: inline-block; }
#container > div.first { float: left; }
```

HTML

```js
<div id="container">
<div>6</div>
<div class="first">1</div>
<div class="first">3</div>
<div>2</div>
<div class="first">5</div>
<div>4</div>
</div>
```

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H9pPW/)

If you want to display one above another, this is the only hacky solution I figured out:

```css
#container { width: 100px; }
#container > div { display: inline-block; float: right; position: relative;
  width: 50px; left: -50px; top: 45px; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; }
#container > div.first { float: left; left: 0; top: 0; }
```

The hack is the `top: 45px;` which is (number of .first elements) * (line-height). I am not sure about cross-browser compatibility here, tested on Chrome.

See [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H9pPW/12/)

Comment: This is close to what I want, but I need to display divs one above the other, as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @TamasPap My guess is you will have to use javascript for this.

Comment: @Brewal Yeah, it seems like.

Comment: @TamasPap don't give up - what do you think about my alternative solution? It is pretty ugly, works only if you know the number of .first elements, yet it is the only one I figured out.

Comment: @JanTuroň Thank you for updating your answer. This is a smart solution, however - as you said - it can't solve the problem in a general case, when the number of elements is unknown. You have my upvote and my gratitude :) I leave this question open for a while, maybe we'll find a pure css solution for the general case.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the appearance and layout with CSS but not structure. That's DOM manipulation and behaviour which for sanity's sake belongs in a scripting environment. Why not use separate semantic classes instead of a generic 'first' class instead?

Comment: I don't want to manipulate structure, I want to manipulate how html tags are displayed.

Comment: And the divs stacking underneath is why inline and priority floats won't work in this case.